# Bash Cannot Move File Into Owned Directory

Tags: bash, shell, permissions, sh, mv

Im having trouble in Bash.

I have plain files in a directory on my desktop. I am trying to move them into a subdirectory within that directory using: `mv "Filename" /"Directoryname"`

However when I use this command, I get an error telling me that the permission was denied.

I am set as the owner of both directories and have should have full permissions. If there is anything I need to provide you to make it easier for you to help me, I will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mv filename subDirectoryName/.`

By placing `/` in front of the directory name in a move sequence, you're telling the shell that you would like it to be placed in a high level folder named `/folder`.

What you want is a sub-directory within your current directory. As you would usually move directories in bash, `../` goes up one directory, and `directory/` implies you are moving into a folder that is within your current directory.